# App Android Studio parou de pegar o Json online do nada

Tags: php, java, android, json

Estou desenvolvendo um APP, onde ele necessita de pegar dados online via Json de uma API, sem fazer nenhuma alteração ele parou de funcionar sendo que estava funcionando normalmente, ja fiz teste no servidor que esta normal.

No java:

```
        //Consulta na API que retorna o JSON
        InputStream input = new URL(Minha_Url_Json).openStream();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(reader);

        //Pegando o JSON
        String json = s.nextLine();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);  //Transformando o Json em Objeto

        //Pegando item especifico do JsonObjeto
        String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
        String id = jsonObj.getString("id");
```

O retorno do servidor:

```
{
   status: "sucess",
   id: "28937"
}
```

No meu manifest ja habilitei a conexão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

O interessante que até ontem estava funcionando normalmente, so que do nada parou de pegar e começou a dizer que o APP android parou.

Error no Java:

```
org.json.jsonexception end of input at character 1 of
```

Comment: Você fez alguma alteração no servidor ou até mesmo no arquivo?

Comment: Não nenhuma, penso eu ser o servidor visto que não há nenhum erro com o código nem com o próprio Json.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi usando:

```
String out = new Scanner(new URL(URL).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        //Comparaçao de strings
        String[] array = out.split("/");
```